# Can I pass and use enum as a variable?

Tags: java, oop, generics, enums, polymorphism

I'm working on some debug tools. What I'm trying to do at this moment is to provide tester with a GUI window that will display `Enum` entries - their names and human readable values. I would like to have the base dialog class as generic as possible, because there are multiple enums to be viewed.

Additionally, some of those enums implement common interface. Eg.

```
public enum DaysOfTheWeek implements CanBeTranslated { ...
```

Therefore I tried to build on that. After thinking for a while, I created this variable:

```
Class<Enum<? extends CanBeTranslated>> entries;
```

I expected to have access to `entries.values()` as in `DaysOfTheWeek.values` but nope, it doesn't seem to work that way. What I wanted to do was:

```
for(CanBeTranslated entry: myMagicEnumVariable.values()) {
    // display entry in GUI
}
```

Is there a way to work with abstract (as in "not specific one") enum within a variable? I need to have access to the enum in order to get **field names**, this is important - if this wasn't the case, I could just use the array of values.

Please also keep in mind that this question is asked from the perspective of

- writing debugging code
- experimenting out of curiosity

I encountered a very hostile attitude from professional Java developpers when I asked weird question about doing things different for fun, hence this disclaimer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Class<? extends CanBeTranslated> entries = DaysOfTheWeek.class;
for (CanBeTranslated entry : entries.getEnumConstants()) {
    // ...
}
```